# How to convert Unicode ebcdic string to ascii string in datastage?

Tags: unix, datastage, ebcdic

I am reading ebcdic format mainframe data as Unicode string for some reason. When I write that data after some transformation, I am in the need of corresponding ascii data.

Comment: Please add a snippet of what you are trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
dd if="EBCDIC_FILE" of="ASCII_FILE" conv=ascii
```

"if" is the Input file, this case the EBCDIC file
"of" is the Output file, this case the ascii file.